# java class main error for crontab

Tags: java

When I try to run the exe jar file in unix:

```
$ java -jar /tnpm_pm_test.jar
```

It runs properly without any errors but when I try to add it in a crontab

```
*/15 * * * * /usr/bin/java java -jar /home/user1/tnpm/tnpm_pm_test.jar &> /dev/null
```

I'm getting the error below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: version
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: version
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
Could not find the main class: version. Program will exit.
```

I'm not sure what exaclty is the difference between running it independently and using crontab. Anyone knows?

```
whereis java = java: /usr/bin/java /etc/java /usr/lib/java /usr/share/java
which java = /usr/bin/java
```

Comment: It's been a while but I think you have "java" one too many times on that crontab line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be an administrator to put the output into /dev/null. So put it into a file
in your home directory and add an entry to the crontab to delete the file occasionally.

Answer (score 1):

refer [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-cron-job-to-run-a-jar-file/) link.

I think the below command will run correctly. Make sure all your dependency jar files in the path /home/user1/tnpm/

```
0/15 * * * * java -jar /home/user1/tnpm/tnpm_pm_test.jar &> /dev/null
or
0/15 * * * * /usr/bin/java -jar /home/user1/tnpm/tnpm_pm_test.jar &> /dev/null
```

Comment: Correct but I still can't run : Permission denied in /dev/null, guess this is more on permission issue. thanks... :)